# CalendarAgent keeps asking for access to "login" after reboot

Tags: macos, calendar, password, keychain, login

I'm running Mountain Lion 10.8.5... and every time I restart my computer or log-out & back in, I get a message box saying that

> "CalendarAgent wants to use "login" keychain".

I've tried repairing the keychain... didn't work.

I've tried setting all names in the login keychain to "Allow all applications to access this keychain".... didn't work.

I've tried deleting the keychain and setting all passwords again... didn't work.

This is beyond frustrating at this point. The only I can seem to get it to quit asking me this is if I delete my exchange account from calendar and quit using it altogether.

Are there any other suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Have the same issue for 2 hours after reboot. And while searching for answer and help, `sudo killall CalendarAgent` doesn't work -- the damn Agent respawns each 10 seconds annoying me with that window.

Comment: At least got the Agent disabled via https://discussions.apple.com/message/19469905#19469905

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do in this situation is rename the "login" keychain in ~/Library/Keychains to something like **login.keychain.old**.

Then I would open the Keychain Access app and drag **login.keychain.old** into the keychains sidebar. OS X will create a new login keychain. So all you have to do is open the old login keychain list you created and drag the passwords into the new login keychain.

Hope this helps.